# The proper style to test a function over a variety of inputs

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, dsl

I need to test a following line:

```
result = handle(streamOfMessages)
```

Where `messages` and `context` are well-populated hashes. I could write the `it` like this:

```
messages1 = [ {"type"=>"someType1","value"=>"someBigHash1"}, {"type"=>"someType2","value"=>"someBigHash2"}, {"type"=>"someType1","value"=>"someBigHash3"} ]
result1 = handle(messages1)
result1.should == [someValue1, someOtherValue1]

messages2 = [ {"type"=>"someType1","value"=>"someBigHash1"}, {"type"=>"someType2","value"=>"someBigHash2"}, {"type"=>"someType1","value"=>"someBigHash3"} ]
result2 = handle(messages1)
result2.should == [someValue2, someOtherValue2]

// same about messages3, result3 etc
```

I could make an array of arrays and refer to `messages[i]` in the loop. However, it all looks to me as a pretty oldskul approach, hence I am looking for a more inspiring (or even should I say *DSL*-based) programming style. It would be great to have a better syntax both for constructing a stream of messages and for iterating over several streams while expecting different results.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically produce separate test cases for each input:

```
[ {"type"=>"someType1","value"=>"someBigHash1"}, {"type"=>"someType2","value"=>"someBigHash2"}, {"type"=>"someType1","value"=>"someBigHash3"} ].each do |h|
  it "should handle #{h[:type]} to return #{h[:value]}" do
     result1 = handle(h)
     result1.should == [value1, value2]
  end
end
```

value1 and value2 are not set here but I hope you get the point - you can also insert them to you array of hashes and compare against them.

Comment: Kindly see the refined question: (1) is there an easier way to construct the test sets (message streams)? (2) is there an easy way to test them?

Answer (score 0):

I would not rewrite the specs in any significant way. In my opinion, unit tests should not contain "clever" code and they should not be refactored and DRYed ad absurdum. The only thing that you want from them is to see whether a piece of code produces the correct output for a given input. And your code already achieves that...

Comment: Unit tests should be DAMP (Descriptive And Meaningful Phrases), not DRY. However, in this specific case, they are neither.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: In that case, what's wrong with the unit test above? Any constructive guideline will be welcomed. Feels very "wrong" to me in the modern age.

Comment: I'd probably write custom RSpec matchers to encapsulate both the responses and the testing logic and give more descriptive names to the messages. Then, the test becomes something like `invalid_message.should be_rejected`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Thanks for the "DAMP", I did not know that acronym.